# Moodle reports from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, moodle, moodle-api

I have a moodle database which I exported a few months ago before our server went down. Now I want to generate reports from my old database, I have tried to import to new moodle site but moodledata folder is missing. So now I'm looking for another way to generate reports from my database. I have tried to make Msql queries but I think that would take a lot of time for now. I need help if there is any tool around which I can use or any API which I can use to generate reports from my database. I have tried to use [Seal Report](https://github.com/ariacom/Seal-Report) to tackle this issue but I have found that there is a lot of manual work to be done, I don't means this tool can't do that but I'm just looking if there is any other tool which can simplify my task.

NB: I know some will say this is not a programming question, Please feel free to suggest any best way to query using any language.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a local copy of a Moodle site with a copy of the database and with a blank Moodle data folder (I've done this regularly in order to investigate issues on a customer's site).

Once you've done that, you will have access to any reporting tools you would normally have inside Moodle.

You may find it easiest to set up a fresh install of Moodle, pointed at a blank database, then, once the install is finished, edit the config.php file to point at the restored copy of the original site. You may have to purge caches (php admin/cli/purge_caches.php) and you may have to reset the admin password (php admin/cli/reset_password.php). It is also wise to turn off email (edit config.php and add $CFG->noemailever = true; ).

Comment: Why do I need to reset the password?

Comment: I didn't say you had to reset the password, I said you '*may* have to reset the password' and gave you instructions about how to do that, if you were unable to login with the admin account.

Comment: I have no access to command line,I'm using shared hosting.How can I do that?

Comment: I was recommending setting up a local copy of the site - assuming you are using a Windows computer, install XAMP (or similar) on your computer (see https://docs.moodle.org/en/Windows_installation_using_XAMPP ), then restore your database onto that computer.